# change list.phtml without changing core list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, php, theme

I've placed some coding in `list.phtml` in `/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product`
but I would like the core file not to be changed. Can somebody help me with this or is there a simple tutorial how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own theme. let's call it `my_theme`.
Copy the file `/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product /list.phtml` to `/app/design/frontend/ultimo/my_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`, do your changes and then go to system->configuration->design and set the theme name `my_theme`.
And in the default theme field put `default`.
This way your template will be used for the product list but for other templates magento will fallback to the `ultimo/default` theme

Comment: thank al lot. great